# Is it possible to submit custom info to Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I'd like to be able to add custom info about a place (specifically restaurants) through the API so that this can be queried later down the line by my app. i.e. display this custom info on the ShowInfoWindow. Is this currently possible?

If not what would be the best way of doing this? Seen as I'm already hooked up to Google App Engine/Console, would it be sensible to create a custom database here that I can query for my own custom info as well as the places API for other info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Places API doesn't provide any way to upload custom fields for places.

So yes, I'd recommend making your own database.  Store your custom data for the Places API results keyed by Place IDs to make it easy to fetch your info for any Places API result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add request using HTTP POST request.
Check this link https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that's not what I mean. I don't want to add new places, I want to add CUSTOM info about an existing place